# Install Cuda GPU Drivers on Google Compute Engine Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cuda, gpu

I am trying to install the CUDA drivers on my GCP Compute Engine VM instance by following Google's instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu)

I run the script for Ubuntu but get this error when I run `sudo apt-get install cuda`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda : Depends: cuda-10-2 (>= 10.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What does this mean and how can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide more details: 1. which GPU do you use? 2. what OS do you use?

Comment: This has been resolved! I had to be using Ubuntu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was on Debian but had to be using Ubuntu!

Thanks!